# Is there a way to give a fixed width and a fixed heigh of a text (string) on the ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]It seems that one can only change the size of the text, which scales the text in both width and height in ggplot. Does anyone know if there is a way to plot a text with a given width and height at a given x, y position on the plot? In another words, I want to be able to stretch the text in x or y dimension without affecting the other, like the image provided here.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [`ggfittext` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggfittext/vignettes/introduction-to-ggfittext.html)

You can play around with it for what you need, but stealing a few examples from its doc gives this :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfittext)
library(ggpubr) # for ggarrange

g1 <- ggplot(animals, aes(x = type, y = flies, label = animal)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "white", colour = "black") +
  geom_fit_text() + ggtitle("no options")

g2 <- ggplot(animals, aes(x = type, y = flies, label = animal)) +
  geom_tile(fill = "white", colour = "black") +
  geom_fit_text(grow = T) + ggtitle("grow = T")

ggarrange(g1, g2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information.I'm sorry, but this is not what I want because it changes the sizes of the text, in another words, it scales both the height and width. I want to be able to stretch the text in one dimension without affecting the other.